# basedir configuration in Maven Archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

How do I configure `basedir` in Maven Archetype to a folder of my choice? The comamnd below does not seem to change it.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=edu.pr.prototype.SpringHibWeb
    -DartifactId=SpringHibWebMVC1 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp 
    -DinteractiveMode=true 
    -Dbasedir=D:\rough\check
```

Comment: I just tested with version 2.2 of the archetype plugin and neither works for me. I found that there is a bug reported for this: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ARCHETYPE-311